# How to Translate Sampling SAS Code into R ?

Tags: r, sas

I am trying to translate a SAS sampling method into r and wondering if there is a comparable r method that I can leverage for the following SAS code.

```
proc surveyselect data=WORK.TEST out=WORK.TEST_Sample
method=srs   /* simple random sample */
rate=0.06;   /* % sample rate */
strata   ZIP /* sorted data required*/
/ alloc=proportional; run;
```

Comment: See the `sample` function.

Comment: Thanks Dave2e, is it a base function?

Comment: Yes, it is a base R function, there are many available options.  Since I don't know SAS, I can't provide a translation. please see the documentation.

Comment: Ya, checked it. But not sure how to pass starta and the the proportional sampling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your SAS code it seems like you need a stratified sample. There are a bunch of ways to do this but the one I would use is `createDataPartition` from the `caret` package. It will output a set of indices that you can use to subset your data. So something like:

```
indices <- createDataPartition(y = TEST$ZIP, 
                               times = 1, 
                               p = 0.06, 
                               list = FALSE) # set this to get a vector as output)

sample <- TEST[indices, ]
```

Then sample should be a 6% cut of your `TEST` dataset, stratified by `ZIP`. (Although beware that if you have a lot of unique values in `ZIP` relative to the size of the dataset you might not get all of them appearing in your `sample`.)

Comment: Also, any thoughts if I need to order data on ZIP or strata?

Comment: Sorry if it's too late for this, only just saw the comment. No, you wouldn't need to order data on ZIP, as it will automatically apportion them.